# How do you convert an Object to an Object Array?

Tags: visual-c++

I am doing a cross thread update (probably in the wrong way but I'm not super concerned about doing it the right way, right now).

```
private: System:: Void doUpdate() {
             cout << "RUNNING";
             array<Object^>^ args = gcnew array<Object^>(1);
             array<Object^>^ inArgs = gcnew array<Object^>(2);
             inArgs[0] = 123;
             inArgs[1] = "Hi";
             args[0] = inArgs;
            this->Invoke(updateDel, args);
         }
```

This successfully calls:

```
private: System::Void crossThreadUpdate(Object obj) {
             /* obj is an object array in the debugger but i can't access it programatically */
             this->progressBar1->Value = 99; // this works
         }
```

Like I said, I'm not trying to learn everything about Visual C++/CLI right now. I just need this simple task to work.

Comment: Your not concerned about doing it right and it successfully works?... what is the question exactly?

Comment: it updates the progress bar but i cant get the values out of obj. in the debugger obj contains Hi and 123 but i can't get those values programatically.

Comment: Do you need to cast it: `array<Object^>^ arr = (array<Object^>^)obj;`?

Comment: When I try that it gives no suitable conversion function from "System::Object" to "cli::array<System::Object ^, 1> ^" exists